# Rewrite module with custom status code doesn't work with this code?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to write some rewrite rules in my web-application so everytime someone make a httprequest with xml accept header I can simply send them response from the file I have in my app.

the given code work fine. I have a problem if I am trying to set custom 515 (for example) IIS start showing exception. If I am trying to use Redirect it's not having the same status code.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="match static xml">
          <match url="testapicalls" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" ignoreCase="true" matchType="Pattern"  negate="true" pattern="xml^" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="sitedown.xml" statusCode="515" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="match static json">
          <match url="testapicalls" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" ignoreCase="true" matchType="Pattern"  negate="true" pattern="json^" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="sitedown.json" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Anyone have any idea how to set the rules to take response from the file and return it with custom statusCode which in my case is 515.

Thanks

Comment: Nope. You can either return a file with 200 response, or a 515 response with only text message. URL Rewrite is not a silver bullet for everything.

Comment: Should I proceed with Using Custom HttpModule or something else.

Comment: Yup, custom IIS module should work.